# Creating a Jquery Plugin for Image Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to convert this Function into a Jquery Plugin so that It may handle any number of Images in the Reel. Or simply any number of Images could be used for this Slider. If required you may Refer to thirteen23.com. I'm trying to make a slider exactly as that used at the Site. I'm a new user to Stack Overflow. Please help and Also tell me the Right way to use this site. Thanks in Advance.
[Link to JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhandelwal/wthyR/2/)

```
-Akshay    


  <div class="main_view">
    <div class="window">
        <div class="image_reel">
            <a href="#">
                <img width="948" src="Images/Home/LIV.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#">
            <img width="948" src="Images/Home/JUM.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#">
            <img width="948" src="Images/Home/LOV.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#">
            <img width="948" src="Images/Home/BLI.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="pictureslide">
            <h2>
                Livestrong</h2>
            <p>
                Mobile donations to fight cancer and improve lives.</p>
            <a href="http://thirteen23.com/work/#livestrong-donation">See more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pictureslide">
            <h2>
                Jumpshot</h2>
            <p>
                The lighter side of serious software.</p>
            <a href="/#jumpshot">See more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pictureslide">
            <h2>
                Flashback</h2>
            <p>
                An exciting way to explore, stylize, and share your Facebook photos.</p>
            <a href="/#flashback">See more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pictureslide">
            <h2>
                Love Universe</h2>
            <p>
                Blurring the line between product and lifestyle.</p>
            <a href="/#love-universe">See more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="paging">
        <a href="#" rel="1">
            <img src="Images/Home/LIV_sm.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#" rel="2">
        <img src="Images/Home/JUM_sm.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#" rel="3">
        <img src="Images/Home/LOV_sm.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#" rel="4">
        <img src="Images/Home/BLI_sm.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
windowObj = {
    imageWidth: 925,
    imagesum: 4
};

var MainPageSlider = function(windowObj) {
    $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");
    //Get size of images, how many there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
    var imageWidth = windowObj.imageWidth;
    var imageSum = windowObj.imagesum + 1;
    var imageReelWidth = (imageWidth * imageSum);
    //Adjust the image reel to its new size
    $(".image_reel").css({
        'width': imageReelWidth
    });
    //Paging + Slider Function
    rotate = function() {
        var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
        var image_reelPosition = triggerID * (imageWidth + 30); //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide
        $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
        $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)
        //Slider Animation
        $(".image_reel").animate({
            left: -image_reelPosition
        }, 500);
    };
    //Rotation + Timing Event
    rotateSwitch = function() {
        play = setInterval(function() { //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 3 seconds
            $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
            if ($active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
            }
            rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
        }, 7000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)
    };
    rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch
    //On Hover
    $(".image_reel a").hover(function() {
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
    }, function() {
        rotateSwitch(); //Resume rotation
    });
    //On Click
    $(".paging a").click(function() {
        $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
        //Reset Timer
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor tag
    });
};
MainPageSlider(windowObj)
```

Comment: it is a good practice to put your code here and also make a jsfiddle