# Jquery Plugin For Image Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a Jquery Plugin for Image Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944935/creating-a-jquery-plugin-for-image-slider)

I'm trying to make a Image Slider Plugin. 
It works on Home Page Perfectly but not sure how do i go about doing the same in Next pages. Here's a link to JS Fiddle

[JsFiddle link to my Example](http://jsfiddle.net/akhandelwal/wthyR/2/)